# Calculate the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{1-e^{-s}}$

Tags: transformation, laplace-transform

During my signals and systems class i came across this and i have to find it's inverse Laplace transform.  I don't know how.

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \Big\{ \frac{1}{1-e^{-s}} \Big\} = \ ?$$

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{1}{1-e^{-s}}=\sum_{n\ge0}e^{-ns}$$

Comment: Have you covered the Laplace transform of periodic functions yet?

Comment: You should end up with an infinite train of Dirac deltas.

Comment: This reminds me the  Fourier, not the Laplace transform..

Comment: @Did i expanded this as a series. That is $(1-e^{-s})^{-1}$. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing the property
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = \frac{\int_{0}^{T} e^{- s u} \, f(u) \, du}{1 - e^{-s T}} 
\end{align}
where $f(t+T) = f(t)$ then
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{1}{1- e^{-s}}\} = \frac{\int_{0}^{1} e^{-su} \, \delta(u) \, du}{1- e^{-s}}
\end{align}
for which $f(t) = \delta(t)$ with the periodic property $f(t+1) = f(t)$. 
This leads to 
$$f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \delta(t-n)$$
Alternatively
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{1-e^{-s}}\right\} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{e^{-ns}\} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \delta(t-n)
\end{align}